# Is the zero vector space $\{0\}$ a simple object in the category of vector spaces over a fixed field?

Tags: vector-spaces, category-theory, abelian-categories

Lets consider the category $\text{Vec}$ of vector spaces over $\mathbb{C}$. A simple object is an object $V$ such that any injection $U \hookrightarrow V$ is either the $0$ map or an isomorphism. I if $U$ is not trivial then there are no injections from $U$ to $\{0 \}$, but I dont know if this means that $\{ 0 \}$ is simple or not. **nLab** argues that the $\{0 \}$ vector space is "too simple to be simple", but I dont know if this is enough to conclude that it is not a simple object in $\text{Vec}$.

Comment: Usually one excludes initial/zero objects from being simple: thus, a simple group is a *nontrivial* group with no proper nontrivial normal subgroups, etc. Under the definition you give, $\{\mathbf{0}\}$ would be simple, but we usually do not want it to be.

Comment: Generally, the trivial object is "too simple to be simple" because of how *simple* is used. Think of the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic (positive integer has unique factorization into primes, up to ordering). If the number $1$ were considered prime (analogous to simple), then this theorem doesn't work as stated.

Comment: What "would be enough to conclude it is not a simple object"?  a "proof of the definition"? stone tablets brought down a mountain?  They are defined to be nonzero because the zero module does not contribute anything to direct sum decompositions, just like units do not contribute anything to prime factorizations.  The only thing you have to be conclusive about is what definition of simple you are using.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the zero object is not considered simple by the standard definition.  It is deliberately left out.

It is not useful to allow the zero object to be simple.  For example, one wants to say something like "A direct sum of simple objects cannot be simple" but that's what you get if the zero object is simple because $\{0\}\oplus \{0\}=\{0\}$.